# easy-align spaces around delimiters

Tags: alignment, plugin-easy-align

I'm using [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) plugin and when in `bash` scripts I try to align `$` at the beginning of variable names, the aligning adds spaces around the delimiter, i.e. `<space>$<space>` which of course makes those variables meaningless.

Are there options or tips to temporarily or permanently disable this? for specific delimiters? That is, to allow spaces around `=` and other delimiters, but not the variable leaders such as `$`.

Should I make a `\$\w` regex instead of just using the `$`?

Comment: What happens if you add `$` to the `iskeyword` option (for `sh` files) ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but doesn't work.  I used `set iskeyword=@,$` with a shell file open and there was no difference in the `easy-align` results - still space on either side.  Same spacey thing with `=` signs and other characters used.

Comment: ok, I've now figured out that the plugin has other variables to set the `margins` on each side of the character to align.  I'll need to create a special function for all uses to make default left and right margins=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileType solution, just for reference to whoever can use it....

```
"---- Easy Align ---- {{{
xmap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)
nmap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)

augroup FileType sh,perl
  let g:easy_align_delimiters = {
      \ 's': {
      \     'pattern':       '\$',
      \     'ignore_groups': ['Comment'],
      \     'left_margin':   0,
      \     'right_margin':  0,
      \     'indentation':   'shallow',
      \     'stick_to_left': 0
      \     },
      \ '=': {
      \     'pattern':       '=',
      \     'ignore_groups': ['Comment'],
      \     'left_margin':   0,
      \     'right_margin':  0,
      \     'indentation':   'deep',
      \     'stick_to_left': 0
      \     }
  \}
  augroup END
"}}}
```